# jnlp and what triggers the download of jars?

Tags: java, jar, download, jnlp

We need to understand what triggers the download of jar files thru JNLP ? Because we want to restrict it from downloading even though there is a new content in server. This is due to some of the slow clients.

To get the latest code, we are planning to download from a dev server in advance and replace it in cache. But somehow it is not working. We are using the same keystore in both dev and prod servers.

Please help me understand what will prevent downloading of the jars from server thru JNLP.

Comment: Surely you can get what you want by appropriate settings of the update/check and update/policy elements without rewriting parts of JWS?